# Pandas DataFrame - remove / replace dict values based on key

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame defined as:

```
df = {
  "customer_name":"john",
  "phone":{
     "mobile":000, 
     "office":111
   },
  "mail":{
    "office":"john@office.com", 
    "personal":"john@home.com",
    "fax":"12345"
   }
 }
```

I want to somehow alter the value in column "mail" to remove the key "fax". Eg, the output DataFrame would be something like:

```
output_df = {
  "customer_name":"john",
  "phone":{
     "mobile":000, 
     "office":111
   },
  "mail":{
    "office":"john@office.com", 
    "personal":"john@home.com"
   }
 }
```

where the "fax" key-value pair has been deleted. I tried to use pandas.map with a dict in the lambda, but it does not work. One bad workaround I had was to normalize the dict, but this created unnecessary output columns, and I could not merge them back. Eg.;

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df)
```

Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pop` to remove a element from `dict` having the given `key`.

```
import pandas as pd
df['mail'].pop('fax')
df = pd.json_normalize(df)
df
```

Output:

> ```
>   customer_name   phone.mobile    phone.office    mail.office     mail.personal
> 0 john            0               111             john@office.com john@home.com
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you just don't access it directly and delete it?
Like this:

```
del df['mail']['fax']
print(df)

{'customer_name': 'john', 
'phone': {'mobile': 0, 'office': 111}, 
'mail': {'office': 'john@office.com', 'personal': 'john@home.com'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest technique to achieve your aim.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = {
  "customer_name":"john",
  "phone":{
     "mobile":000, 
     "office":111
   },
  "mail":{
    "office":"john@office.com", 
    "personal":"john@home.com",
    "fax":"12345"
   }
 }
del df['mail']['fax']
df = pd.json_normalize(df)
df
```

*Output :*

> ```
> customer_name phone.mobile    phone.office    mail.office mail.personal 
> 0 john    0   111            john@office.com  john@home.com
> ```